# Why can't PowerShell Remove-Item remove an empty on-demand folder from OneDrive?

Tags: powershell, onedrive

This fails:

```
New-Item "C:\Users\User1\OneDrive - Tenant\Test" -ItemType Directory
Remove-Item "C:\Users\User1\OneDrive - Tenant\Test"
```

With the error:

> Test is an NTFS junction point. Use the Force parameter to delete or modify this object.

So add -Force to end and you get:

> Remove-Item : Access to the cloud file is denied

This is with OneDrive configured to use on-demand files. Except the folder does indeed exist locally because we've just created it. Configure OneDrive to no use on-demand files and it deletes okay.

Good old RMDIR "Folder" /S /Q in CMD.EXE works fine...

Any ideas why this is happening? Seems a pretty basic requirement.

Comment: If I were to guess this is a bug with [Remove-Item](https://superuser.com/questions/1601754/onedrive-access-to-the-cloud-file-is-denied) based on the number of results I am finding for the error.  How large are these files?

Comment: It's an empty folder - no files involved. But yes, I'm pretty sure it's a bug. Not the first time I've encountered similar with PowerShell and OneDrive on-demand. A couple of my scripts have a function at the top that forces OneDrive to download files/folders as it just doesn't work with on-demand. But this post was triggered by a script that's been working for a couple of years failing to remove a folder

Comment: As per discussion on the [Fix Remove-Item <symbolic link to directory>
#621](https://github.com/powershell/powershell/issues/621) post, use something like `(get-item $removethispathreparsepoint).Delete()` or `function Remove-SymLinks {
    Get-ChildItem -Force -ErrorAction Stop @Args | Where-Object { if($_.Attributes -match "ReparsePoint"){$_.Delete()} }
}` to delete the junction point specifically. Read over the GitHub post and comments for more detail too.

Comment: Thanks for the reference - makes a simple one line to remove folder and children more complex :-( But why is it taking over four years to fix??